# bootstrap dropdown menu issue on mobile and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have this menu and it was working fine but since yesterday it doesn't work on chrome and mobile platforms .
I did not change anything in the code at all.

The problem is when i am clicking init, the menu  closes.

This is my code:

```html
<header id="top">
  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="headerBG"></div>
    <div class="container bposi">
      <h1 id="logo"> <a title="MIR" href="#"> <img title="" alt="" src="images/kkkk.png"> </a> </h1>
      <div class="navbar-header navBox">
        <div>
          <button data-target=".navbar-main-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button"> </button>
          <a title="Login" id="btnLoginRes" href="#" class="btn btn-login btn-loginMobile "><span>Login</span></a>
          <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse collapse " aria-expanded="true" style="">
            <ul class="navigation" id="mainNav">
              <li class="hasSubMenu" ><a title="Products" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" href="#"><span>Products</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="http://www.google.com" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img" /><strong>1</strong></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img1.png" /><strong>2</strong></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img2.png" /><strong>3</strong></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img3.png" /><strong>4</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Softwares" href="#"><span>Softwares</span></a></li>
              <li><a title="Info" href="#"><span>Info</span></a></li>
              <li><a title="Contact" href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
              <li  class="hasSubMenu subMenudownload"><a title="Downloads" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" href="#"><span>Downloads</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img-1.png" /><strong>1</strong></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img-2.png" /><strong>2</strong></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="" src="images/img-3.png" /><strong>3</strong></a></li>
              
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="hasSubMenu"><a title="English" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><span>English</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu noImg">
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><strong>English</strong></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title=""><strong>Arabic</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a title="Search" href="#" class="icon-search" id="btnSearch"><span>Search</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <input id="fieldSearch" type="text" class="input-text" placeholder="Search " />
          <a title="Search" href="#" class="icon-close" id="btnClose"><span>&nbsp;</span></a>
          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</header>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in console? Especially when you click on the menu to collapse?

Comment: no, i don't get any errors, the menu is working on firefox and IE but on chrome and mobile it is not working, it is dropping down but the links inside the submenu aren't clickable when i am trying to click on any link the menu is closing

Comment: btw it was working before, but two days ago it stopped working and i can't figure out why? even i made no changes at all

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

added this to my css and it is working fine now

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It is a bug in your version of bootstrap. It used position: fixed, together with a z-index. which put it in-front of the sibling menu options.